# initializing a matrix, expected expression error in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

So I have tried looking up a few things that seemed helpful, but ultimately were not.

I am supposed to initialize a 6x8 matrix as a 2D array in a separate function. I have three files, a main function file, a functions file, and a header file.

Here is relevant code from main

```
     int plate[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

double A = 0, B = 0, T1 =0, T2 = 0, C = 0;

printf("\n");
printf("Welcome to the Heat Plate Simulation\n\n");
printf("Enter: Heat-A, Heat-B, Plate-1, Plate-2, Stab-Crit\n\n");
scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &A,&B,&T1,&T2,&C);
```

then I try

```
    initialize_plate(plate,T1, T2);
```

which goes to

```
    void initialize_plate(int plate[][MAX_COLS],double T1, double T2)
    {
 plate[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = {
    { T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T2},
    { T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T2},
    { T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T2},
    { T2, T2, T2, T1, T1, T1},
    { T2, T2, T2, T1, T1, T1},
    { T2, T2, T2, T1, T1, T1} 
    };
return;
    }
```

The error I receive is 7P_functions.c:14:32: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
   *plate[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = {

Given what I have researched with this error my only guess is that it has something to do with the array already being initialized, but I am not sure how to rectify this problem whereas if I initialize the array within the function and not in main doesn't it just become a local variable?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assignment is not equivalent to initialization. You have to loop over the each index to assign values.

Comment: type of `plate` elements is `int`, but type of `T1` and `T2` is `double`.

Comment: I changed those to both be doubles, thank you, saw that while trying to fix this as well

Comment: it would be a good idea to allow, at least, a space between the input numbers of this line: scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &A,&B,&T1,&T2,&C);  Also, the returned value from the call to scanf() needs to be checked to assure that all the conversions of the format string were successful.  In this case, the value should be 5

Comment: the code is placing double values 'T1' 'T2' into an integer array.  This means LOTS of conversions from double (8 bytes) to int (4 bytes)  if you define 'plate' as a double, then no conversions are needed.

Comment: @user3629249: `"%lf"` consumes leading whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Set the value using `memcpy` from the temporary array.

```
void initialize_plate(int plate[][MAX_COLS],double T1, double T2){
    memcpy(plate, (int [][MAX_COLS]){
        { T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T2},
        { T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T2},
        { T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T2},
        { T2, T2, T2, T1, T1, T1},
        { T2, T2, T2, T1, T1, T1},
        { T2, T2, T2, T1, T1, T1} },
        6*sizeof(int [MAX_COLS]));

    return;
}
```

Comment: maybe I copied this wrong, but I get: error: ISO C90 forbids compound literals [-Wpedantic]
     memcpy(plate, (int [][MAX_COLS]){

Comment: @puzzlekid you can like this : `int temp[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = {...}; memcpy(plate, temp, sizeof(temp));` or use option `-std=c99` or something else.

Comment: If I do It your way, or another way that I tried, not sure if it works yet or not, but either way I get the error of
7P_functions.c:18:3: error: initializer element is not computable at load time

Comment: @puzzlekid ah, yes. Do not be compiled in C99?

Comment: see this is where my ignorance shows, but I don't know. We use PuTTy, I type gcc to compile my functions, but the specifics I don't know and am not sure how to find out, but will look into it

Comment: @puzzlekid you can C99 If you are using the gcc. e.g `gcc -pedantic -std=c99 7P_functions.c`

Comment: this will not quite work as expected because the values used are doubles and plate and temp are int.

Answer (score 0):

this plate[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = {...};
tries to reserve a place in memory, with initialization.
you can't use this method to modify the values of an array.

Comment: Thank you for your input, combining that with the comment above I see have to do the difference and will change the code