# Pass 2D array by reference

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, pass-by-reference

I want to be able to pass a 2D array to a function, and have it directly change the array in main, so pass by reference.  When I try to compile, I get `error: expected expression before {` in the switch cases.  (boardSize=10, but that is not known at compilation time)

```
void fillBoard(int **, int);

int main() {
    int **board = malloc(sizeof(int *) * boardSize);
    fillBoard(board, boardSize);
}

void fillBoard(int **board) {
    int i, *row = malloc(sizeof(int) * boardSize);
    for (i=0; i<boardSize; i++) {
        board[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * boardSize);
        switch(i) {
            case 1: row = {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}; break;
            default: row = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; break;
        }
        board[i] = row;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int **` is not equivalent to `int[N][M]`. One is a pointer to a pointer, the other is an array of arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26877227/971127

Comment: `void fillBoard(int board[][boardsize]);`

Comment: Which C book are you reading/have read?

Comment: I just noticed the question is tagged "C". There aren't references in C. And here's another thing that doesn't make sense: the size of the board isn't known at compile time, but the contents of the board are (which you have hard-coded)?

Comment: For the release version, we don't know the size, because the user can choose the size.  But it defaults to 10x10 if they don't input anything.  And the default 10x10 is what we are using for testing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [initializing a matrix, expected expression error in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876854/initializing-a-matrix-expected-expression-error-in-c)

Comment: Had to upvote the answer on the duplicate question in order to "mark as duplicate"

Comment: You can only initialise a declared array like that `int row[] = {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0};`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between double \*\* and double (\*)\[2\] in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633110/difference-between-double-and-double-2-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

There a many different ways to do this. The key is to keep track of what you are addressing where. You can use a `single` or `double` pointer to pass and fill `board`, it all depends on how you want to keep track of the elements. (while the 2-dimensional array, provides a convenience in referencing elements, all values are sequential in memory, and can be accessed with a 1-dimensional reference and offset).

There is one important suggestion when allocating memory for `numeric` arrays. You must always initialize **all** elements of the array to protect against attempting to access or dereference an uninitialized value (Undefined behavior). The simple way to do this is to allocate with `calloc` instead of `malloc`. `calloc` allocates **and** initializes all values to `zero` (`NULL`).

Also be aware of the need to track the memory you allocate over the life of your program and `free` the memory when you no longer need it. This will prevent memory leaks from developing. In a short bit of code like the following, the memory is freed when the program exits. If this were part of some larger code, you would need to free `board` and `board2` when there data was no longer needed.

An example using your original array would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define boardSize 10

void fillBoard_p (int *a);
void fillBoard_p2p (int **a);

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    /* declaring board as an integer pointer */
    int *board = calloc (boardSize * boardSize, sizeof (*board));

    /* declaring board as a pointer to pointer */
    int **board2 = calloc (boardSize, sizeof (*board2));
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
        board2[i] = calloc (boardSize, sizeof (**board2));
    }

    fillBoard_p (board);
    fillBoard_p2p (board2);

    printf ("\nboard as an integer pointer:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize * boardSize; i++) {
        if (i % boardSize == 0)
            printf ("\n %d", board[i]);
        else
            printf (" %d", board[i]);
    }

    printf ("\n");

    printf ("\nboard2 as an pointer to integer pointer:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
            printf (" %d", board2[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }    
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}

void fillBoard_p(int *a) {
    // 0=WHITE, 1=BLACK
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int b [][boardSize] = {
        {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}, 
        {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0}, 
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1}
    };

    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < boardSize; j++)
            a[i*boardSize+j] = b[i][j];
}

void fillBoard_p2p (int **a) {
    // 0=WHITE, 1=BLACK
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int b [][boardSize] = {
        {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}, 
        {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0}, 
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1}
    };

    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < boardSize; j++)
            a[i][j] = b[i][j];
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/fillboard

board as an integer pointer:

 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1

board2 as an pointer to integer pointer:

 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

Additionally, since a `2-D array` is stored sequentially in memory, you can take advantage of that fact and make use of `memcpy` (in `string.h`) to fill the array passed to your function. This can reduce your function to:

```
void fillBoard_mc (int *a) {
    // 0=WHITE, 1=BLACK
    int b [][boardSize] = {
        {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}, 
        {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0}, 
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1}
    };
    memcpy (a, b, boardSize * boardSize * sizeof (int));
}
```

Were it not for the particularity of the compiler and `pointer decay`, you could simply use a statically declared array, such as:

```
int board[boardSize][boardSize] = {{0}};
```

passing the address of the array to your function (becoming a **3-star** programmer):

```
fillBoard (&board);
```

with a function similar to:

```
void fillBoard (int *a[][boardSize]) {
    // 0=WHITE, 1=BLACK
    int b [][boardSize] = {
        {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0}, 
        {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0}, 
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1},
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},A
        {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1}
    };
    memcpy (a, b, boardSize * boardSize * sizeof (int));
}
```

Due to pointer decay (`board[10][10]` => `board[*][10]`), you will receive an `incompatible pointer type` warning, despite the function successfully copying the memory as intended. Code that does not compile without warning, should not be relied on in practice.